# IN operator only returns if parameter is a specific value

Tags: php, sql

I have a questions table (that contains questions) and a tags table (that contains tags (represented by integers) for each question).

What I am trying to do is get a list of questions that have the same tag as that in the `IN` operator.

However, the query currently returns all the questions if `1` is there and 0 if it isn't there. It doesn't return questions whose tag integer matches the `IN` operator.

Here is a SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2ded3/2

Answer (score 1):

It seems `id` in `id = questions_tags.q_id` is somehow ambiguous. If you do more specific, it succeeds:

```
SELECT id FROM questions WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM questions_tags WHERE
          questions.id = questions_tags.q_id AND
          questions_tags.t_id IN (1)
);
```

Comment: Problem is, I will have numerous combinations of numbers between 1 and 6, so I can't specifically write out a number in the query. It's all passed down from another method.

Comment: I'm not specifying any number in the query. Worry about whats in the `IN (...)` group.

Answer (score 0):

May be I am wrong But according to what i have understand from the question this query might be helpful:-

```
SELECT questions.id,
       questions_tags.id
FROM   questions,
       questions_tags
WHERE  questions.id = questions_tags.id
       AND questions_tags.t_id IN ( 1 );
```

Hope this helps;